# Escaping multi-line text with "jq"

Tags: json, bash, escaping, jq

Suppose, I need to escape a multi-line text:

```
printf "\"aaa\"\nbbb"  
"aaa"
bbb
```

I'm trying to escape it with `jq -aR`:

```
printf "\"aaa\"\nbbb"| jq -aR 
"\"aaa\""
"bbb"
```

Unfortunately it's not what I want. I want to get `"\"aaa\"\nbbb"` instead.
How can I escape `"aaa"\nbbb` with `jq` properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the --slurp/-s command-line option.

```
$ printf "\"aaa\"\nbbb"| jq -asR 
"\"aaa\"\nbbb"
```

Of course in this case, the `-a` option makes no difference.